# MVC EF upload image and write to DB at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, image, entity-framework

I am quite new to MVC and coding, so apologies if I don't bring it to the point. I am encountering a weird issue that I somehow cannot manage to solve:

I want to submit a form that includes an image along with other values, such as user name, user ID, timestamp, etc. and write it into a table (SQL); now I can get the image as byte to the DB and I can get the form submitted to the DB, but **for some reason I cannot get it done at the same time**, so it's either the image/file or the form. The error I encounter is the following:

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

View Model:

```
namespace errandomWeb.Models
{
    public class PhotoCompetition
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public byte[] CompetitionPicture { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "by checking this box I accept the Terms & Conditions")]
        public bool TermsAndConditionsAccepted { get; set; }

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (getting error message):

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UploadCompetitionPicture(PhotoCompetition model)
        {
            string croppedImage = Request.Form["photoCompetitionCroppedPicture"];
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(croppedImage);
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var participation = new PhotoCompetition
            {
                CompetitionPicture = imageBytes,
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = "testcase",
                Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
                TermsAndConditionsAccepted = true,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
            };
            DB.PhotoCompetition.Add(participation);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return View("Edit");
        }
    }
```

Controller (working for image, but not the form...):

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UploadCompetitionPicture()
        {
            string croppedImage = Request.Form["photoCompetitionCroppedPicture"];
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(croppedImage);
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var participation = new PhotoCompetition
            {
                CompetitionPicture = imageBytes,
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = "testcase",
                Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
                TermsAndConditionsAccepted = true,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
            };
            DB.PhotoCompetition.Add(participation);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return View("Edit");
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model errandomWeb.Models.PhotoCompetition
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Become Our Model";
}
<div id="photoCompetitionContainer" class="manageContainer">
    <div id="photoCompetitionHeaderSection" class="manageHeaderSection">
        <h1 id="photoCompetitionHeaderTitle" class="manageHeaderTitle">
            @ViewBag.Title
        </h1>
        <img id="photoCompetitionHeaderProfilePicture" class="manageHeaderProfilePicture" src="@Url.Action("UserPicture", "Manage")" />
        <p id="photoCompetitionHeaderPersonalizationGeneric" class="manageHeaderPersonalization">
            Hello
        </p>
        <p id="photoCompetitionHeaderPersonalizationName" class="manageHeaderPersonalization">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @id = "photoCompetitionHeaderUserName", @class = "manageHeaderUserName", @placeholder = "Stranger", @disabled = true })
        </p>
    </div>
    @Html.Partial("_ProfileLogout")
    <div id="photoCompetitionContextSection" class="manageContextSection">
        <p id="photoCompetitionContext" class="manageContext">
            Want to become our model?
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="photoCompetitionValidationSection" class="manageValidation">
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @id = "photoCompetitionValidation", @class = "manageValidation" })
    </div>
    <section id="photoCompetition" class="manageForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadCompetitionPicture", "errandom", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "photoCompetitionForm", @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="photoCompetitionSection" class="manageSection">
                <p id="photoCompetitionSectionTitle" class="manageSectionTitle">
                    Upload your picture and be selected as our model!
                </p>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TimeStamp)
                <div id="photoCompetitionProfilePictureArea" class="manageArea row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompetitionPicture, new { @id = "photoCompetitionProfilePictureLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4" })
                    <a id="photoCompetitionProfilePictureSelectionButton" class="manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6" href="#">
                        select a file...
                    </a>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompetitionPicture, new { @id = "photoCompetitionProfilePictureField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6", @type = "file", @style = "display: none" })
                </div>
                <div id="photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsArea" class="manageArea row">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TermsAndConditionsAccepted, new { @id = "photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsField", @class = "photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsField" })
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TermsAndConditionsAccepted, new { @id = "photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsLabel", @class = "photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsLabel" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TermsAndConditionsAccepted, "", new { @id = "photoCompetitionTermsAndConditionsValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
                </div>
                <script>
                    jQuery("#photoCompetitionProfilePictureSelectionButton").click(function () {
                        $("#photoCompetitionProfilePictureField").click();
                    });
                </script>
                <script>
                    $("#photoCompetitionProfilePictureField").change(function () {
                        var fullFileName = $("#photoCompetitionProfilePictureField").val()
                        $("#photoCompetitionProfilePictureSelectionButton").html(fullFileName.substr(fullFileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
                    });
                </script>
                <div id="photoCompetitionCroppingArea" class="manageArea row">
                    <img id="photoCompetitionOriginal" class="photoCompetitionImage" src="" alt="" style="display: none" />
                    <canvas id="photoCompetitionCropped" class="photoCompetitionImage" height="5" width="5"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="photoCompetitionButtonArea" class="manageArea row">
                    <input id="photoCompetitionButtonCrop" class="manageButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" type="button" value="Crop" style="display: none" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionButtonUpload" class="manageButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" type="submit" value="Save" style="display: none" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionCropX" class="photoCompetitionData" name="photoCompetitionCropX" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionCropY" class="photoCompetitionData" name="photoCompetitionCropY" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionCropW" class="photoCompetitionData" name="photoCompetitionCropW" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionCropH" class="photoCompetitionData" name="photoCompetitionCropH" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="photoCompetitionCroppedPicture" class="photoCompetitionData" name="photoCompetitionCroppedPicture" type="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </section>
    <div id="photoCompetitionReturnToMenuSection" class="manageReturnToMenuSection">
        @Html.ActionLink("Return to Menu", "Index", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "photoCompetitionReturnToMenuButton", @class = "manageReturnToMenuButton" })
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/master/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if ($('#photoCompetitionCroppingArea').width() > 700) {
                $('#photoCompetitionProfilePictureField').change(function () {
                    $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').hide();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').show();
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').attr("src", e.target.result);
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').Jcrop({
                            onChange: SetCoordinates,
                            onSelect: SetCoordinates,
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            boxWidth: 600,
                            addClass: 'photoCompetitionCropping'
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#photoCompetitionProfilePictureField').change(function () {
                    $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').hide();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').show();
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').attr("src", e.target.result);
                        $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').Jcrop({
                            onChange: SetCoordinates,
                            onSelect: SetCoordinates,
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            boxWidth: 250,
                            addClass: 'photoCompetitionCropping'
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                });
            }
            $('#photoCompetitionButtonCrop').click(function () {
                var x1 = $('#photoCompetitionCropX').val();
                var y1 = $('#photoCompetitionCropY').val();
                var height = $('#photoCompetitionCropH').val();
                var width = $('#photoCompetitionCropW').val();
                var canvas = $("#photoCompetitionCropped")[0];
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.width = width;
                    context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
                    $('#photoCompetitionCroppedPicture').val(image);
                    $('#photoCompetitionButtonUpload').show();
                    $('#photoCompetitionCropped').hide();
                    $('#photoCompetitionButtonCrop').hide();
                };
                img.src = $('#photoCompetitionOriginal').attr("src");
            });
        });
        function SetCoordinates(c) {
            $('#photoCompetitionCropX').val(c.x);
            $('#photoCompetitionCropY').val(c.y);
            $('#photoCompetitionCropW').val(c.w);
            $('#photoCompetitionCropH').val(c.h);
            $('#photoCompetitionButtonCrop').show();
        };
    </script>
}
```

If anyone has an idea on how I could submit the image while also submitting the other properties I would highly appreciate guidance/advice! Thank you!

Comment: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string" Well, what exactly does `Request.Form["photoCompetitionCroppedPicture"]` contain?  Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it done. Here's the updated controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadCompetitionPicture([Bind(Exclude = "CompetitionPicture")]PhotoCompetition model)
{
    string croppedImage = Request.Form["photoCompetitionCroppedPicture"];
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(croppedImage);
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var participation = new PhotoCompetition
    {
        UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        FirstName = "Ken",
        Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
        TermsAndConditionsAccepted = true,
        TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
    };
    participation.CompetitionPicture = imageBytes;
    DB.PhotoCompetition.Add(participation);
    DB.SaveChanges();
    return View("Edit");
}
```

I guess, what made the difference is excluding the picture in the first place, then submitting all other fields and after that adding the picture separately. Not sure why, but glad I figured it out.

Comment: Interesting FirstName you've got there.